# Jquery autocomplete variable not working

Tags: jquery

Is there any reason why the following might not pass the "checkit" variable onto the countryselect.php page?

```
$(function () {
    $('#abbrev').val("");
    $('#country').on('change', function () {
        alert($("#country").val());
    });
    $("#state").autocomplete({
        source: "/countrycomplete.php?checkit=" + $("#country").val(),
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
        }
    });
});
```

The alert () is there just to see if the variable is there, and this produces the expected result. However, this line, - source: "/countrycomplete.php?checkit="+$( "#country").val(), - does not send the variable on to countrycomplete.php

Any ideas?

I have gone through a number of other posts here related to the same question, but none so far have presented a working solution....I bet there must be some really tiny mistake, but...so far I haven't been able to find it.

EDITED VERSION:

```
$(function() {
    $('#abbrev').val("");
    $('#country').on('change', function(){
        $( "#state" ).autocomplete({
            "option", 
            "source", 
            "/countrycomplete.php?checkit="+$(this).val(),
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
                $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the autocomplete plugin is initialized on page load and gets the value of the input *at that time*, and since the input at page load is probably empty the value is empty as well.

You need to update the autocomplete's URL when the input value changes. You don't mention which autocomplete plugin this is, but assuming it's the jQuery UI one you'd do it this way:

```
$('#country').on('change', function(){
    $( "#state" ).autocomplete( 
        "option", 
        "source", 
        "/countrycomplete.php?checkit="+$(this).val() 
    );
});
```

(Unrelated side note: [don't use `alert()` for debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx).)

Comment: $(function() {  
    $('#abbrev').val("");  
 $('#country').on('change', function(){  
  $( "#state" ).autocomplete({  
   "option",   
   "source",   
   "/countrycomplete.php?checkit="+$(this).val(),  
   minLength: 2,  
   select: function(event, ui) {  
    $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);  
    $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);  
   }  
  });  
 });  
});

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say, and the code is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, my laptop battery ran out before I could edit my comment. I added the other stuff from my initial code (above, to the question), should something like this be working? (it isn't for me though, and yes, I know I'm a dumbass when it comes to jquery)

Comment: Or actually, even if I don't make any changes to it, your version doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$(".selector").autocomplete({
   source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
   select: function (event, ui) {
   var state = ui.item.value;
   console.log(state);  
   $('#state_id').val(state);}
  });
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/DrDrQ/